# Gitolite permission: allowing write tags but not commits

Tags: git, gitolite

My cenario: I have a gitolite environment with two groups, developers and servers. At the begining, servers having only read permission was enough, but now we have a script that executes a git pull and creates a tag for we can know the exact time and person who did the deploy. It works perfectly fine, but I would like to prevent commits comming from servers. Only developers on their computers can write code at the repository, but there's people pushing code from the servers.

I alread tested the permission RW, RW+ and RW+C, with no success. So I would like to know if there's any way I can allow servers to push tags to the repository but not commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitolite should support restricting on tag with **[refexes](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/#the-refex-field)**:

> A refex is a word I made up to mean "a regex that matches a ref".

That means you can disallow a repo, but allow only tags

```
RW  refs/tags/v[0-9]    =   bob
```

In other words, `RW` or other permission alternatives are not enough. You need the proper refex as well.

As the [OP Everton Leite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275214/everton-leite) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471125/gitolite-permission-allowing-write-tags-but-not-commits/46478452#comment79915656_46478452):

```
RW refs/tags/.* = @servers
```

Comment: Well, that definitelly pointed to the right direction! I used `RW refs/tags/.* = @servers` and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EvertonLeite Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.